# How to stop Swing timer inside the anonymous class?

Tags: java, swing

Im making a guessing game but
Im having a problem in Swing timer, because I cant stop it when i putted an IF statement.
This is the part of my code where I encountered  the problem.

```
continueButton.addActionListener(new  ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        f.add(firstPicblur);
        f.invalidate();
        f.remove(loadingEffectBtn);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.repaint(); 
        Timer tt = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {                
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                f.add(firstPiclabelA,BorderLayout.NORTH);
                f.invalidate();
                f.remove(loadingEffect);
                f.setVisible(true);
                f.repaint();
                score01.setText("Score: " + gScore);
                gScore--;                     
            }
        });
        tt.start();
        tt.setRepeats(true); 
        if(gScore == 980){
            tt.stop();
```

P.S this is the last problem that im solving in my Guessing Game, after this everything will be OK.

Comment: You want to check that condition in button click ?

Comment: No, when i clicked the continueButton. the (Score + int x = 1000;) will be added in North part of the frame and when the int x reached 980 the timer will stop.

Comment: Put the check inside the ActionListener of the Swing Timer after `gScore--;`.

Comment: The if statement after the line gScore--; ?

Comment: Yep.. And make tt final (`final Timer tt = ...`).

Comment: I tried it but it gets error. it says "The local variable tt may not have been initialized"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Timer` is the source of the action event, so you can use it, if you don't want to make it a field of the class:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ...
    gscore--;
    if (gScore == 980) {
        ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved my problem and you answer helps me a lot in doing my project. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: A way better approach than mine. +1

Answer (score 2):

I've mislead you in the comments. Instead of making `tt` final, make it a member of the enclosing class. Here's an example:

```java
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerTest extends JFrame {

    private JLabel label = new JLabel("default");
    private Timer timer;   
    private int gScore = 985;

    public TimerTest() {
        add(label);
        pack();

        timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                gScore--;
                if (gScore == 980) {
                    timer.stop();
                }
                label.setText(String.valueOf(gScore));
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                TimerTest test = new TimerTest();
                test.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

You need to call it's constructor only once, and then rely on it's `start()` and `stop()` methods, so your code should look similar to this:

```
continueButton.addActionListener(new  ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        f.add(firstPicblur);
        f.invalidate();
        f.remove(loadingEffectBtn);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.repaint(); 
        tt.start();
}
```

Comment: but my code format is //public class name{
public static void main(string[] args){
//all the panels,buttons, anonymous class.

Comment: @Java-Newbie best to distance yourself from that habit. For any non-trivial program `main()` is just an entry point. Also pay attention to that `invokeLater()` in predi's code. It's *required* for swing thread safety, even though your code may appear to work without it. (So the correct code will also look messy due to too many indents if you try doing everything in `main()`).

Comment: so when i make a program next time, I should put all my components before the line //public static void main(String[] args) {}?

Comment: @Java-Newbie Generally using local variables for stuff that does not need to be accessed elsewhere is *fine*, because it keeps the instance data at minimum. Just try to not fit everything in `main()`, that's not a scalable approach. Split the program into logical parts and you'll find it a lot easier to try reading your own code a year later.

Comment: @kiheru ok, ill try it someday after finishing my Guessing Game. Thanks again!